# Openstack Instance launch Failing

Tags: openstack-nova

I am getting the below error while trying to launch instance in openstack env.

> Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "myvm1", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: No sql_connection parameter is established].

I am new to Openstack.

Comment: This is the right place for you to start learning :) https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/openstack-services.html

Comment: I have faced this problem before in a multi node environment. But in order to help you, I require more details in your problem statement.

Comment: This problem might be because of your connection parameter in one of the configurations for services like nova, neutron, rabbitmq. If you have configured it correctly, it might be due to missing the bind-address in mysql.d.conf.